# List of variables in jekyll post

Tags: jekyll

1 ---
 2 layout: post
 3 title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
 4 date:   2018-06-03 11:57:53 +0300
 5 categories: jekyll update
**5a somevar: sw1 sw2 sw3 sw4**
 6 ---

in "standart" variables of default post i add somevar (line 5a)
i need in result:

SOME VARIABLES:
- sw1
- sw2
- sw3
- sw4

p.s. the quantity of "swX" can be a miscellaneous

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array (in your .md file), like this:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date: 2018-06-03 11:57:53 +0300
categories: jekyll update
somevar: 
  - sw1 
  - sw2 
  - sw3 
  - sw4
---
```

Output the front matter (in your layout) like this:

```
{% for item in page.somevar %}
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but only:
{% for item in page.somevar %}
@JoostS

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. I have updated the answer.